# WCF RIA Services DataAnnotations not working as expected

Tags: silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm having a hard time understanding why my DataAnnotation attributes aren't be used by the client DataForm. Below is the metadata attribute on a phone number field.

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid phone number.")]
        public string client_phone_home { get; set; }
```

When running the application, I can enter any string less than 10 digits in length. It can be letters, numbers, etc. If I enter more than 10 characters, the datavalidation throws a message saying that the client_phone_home field must be a string less than 10 characters in length. It doesn't use my error message, and doesn't indicate anything about the field requiring a valid phone number.

Anyone know why this dataannotation is not working on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-6-Validating-Data.aspx .It has complete explaination about Data Annotation Validation Attributes,Custom Validation Attributes,Server-Side Validation.
and look into this also http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/07/27/silverlight-and-wcf-ria-services-6-validation.aspx